# stdin.write() being blocked from interacting with foil.exe

Tags: python, stdin, popen

I'm writing a wrapper for Xfoil and my first command set of commands are:

```
commands=[]

commands.append('plop\n')
commands.append('g,f\n')
commands.append('\n')
commands.append('load '+ afile+'\n')
commands.append('\n')
#commands.append('ppar\n');
#commands.append('n %g\n',n);
commands.append('\n')
commands.append('\n')
commands.append('oper\n')
commands.append('iter '+ str(iter) + '\n')
commands.append('visc {0:f}\n'.format(Re))
commands.append('m {0:f}\n'.format(M))
```

I'm interacting with xfoil as below:

```
xfoil_path=os.getcwd()+'/xfoil.exe'
Xfoil = Popen(xfoil_path, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=None, stderr=None, creationflags=0)
for i in commands:
    print '\nExecuting:', i
    #stdin.write returns None if write is blocked and that seems to be the case here
    Xfoil.stdin.write(i)
    Xfoil.wait()
    #print Xfoil.stdin.write(i)
```

However, Xfoil.stdin.write is being blocked form interacting with the program -- xfoil.exe --  as Xfoil.stdin.write(i) returns a None.

This happens immediately after the first command i.e. *plop*

How do I resolve this?

Comment: You are waiting for the program to end after you write the _first_ `command` item. Are you sure that's not a/the source of problem? BTW `shell=True` is unnecessary here. Paths should be combined with `os.path.join()`. The building of `commands` with all those `append()` calls looks odd. Why not just create a list with those contents instead of creating an empty one and do all those `append()`s. `i` is a bad name for something that's not an integer, especially as loop variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to add Xfoil.stdin.close(); Closing the buffer allows the program to proceed.

```
Xfoil = Popen(xfoil_path, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=None, stderr=None, creationflags=0)
for i in commands:
    Xfoil.stdin.write(i)

Xfoil.stdin.close()
Xfoil.wait()
```

Seeking help understand why Xfoil.stdin.close() needs to be added. How does closing the buffer allow xfoil.exe to proceed?

Comment: Because only if you `flush()` or `close()` the file ensures the buffered data is actually written to that pipe.

Comment: @BlackJack: `bufsize=0` on Python 2; you don't need `flush()` here.

Answer (score 0):

To send multiple commands, you could [use `Popen.communicate()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) that sends commands, closes the pipe, and waits for the child process to finish:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(os.path.abspath('xfoil.exe'), stdin=PIPE)
process.communicate(b"".join(commands))
```

`Xfoil.wait()` in your code waits for the executable to finish after the first command. Closing the pipe (`Xfoil.stdin`) indicates EOF otherwise the deadlock may happen if `xfoil.exe` read until EOF (no command makes it exit otherwise).